# Warning: SEOChat has been compromised

Tags: discussion

Just as a warning, SEOChat has been compromised. This is not the first time either. Your browser will be hijacked.

If you make the same mistake I did, it is best to dump your computer, power off, reboot, and scan for viruses. If you have a good anti-virus, you will be fine. Still, scan your system then dump your browser cache.

Also, if you find hits on seemingly perfect valid JS apps or libraries, that should be okay. JS can often have false hits.

Comment: As in a website with articles about how to handle a hacked site has been hacked and is serving malware?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes. One of the reasons why I mention it. It is a site we could all possibly go during research. I was collecting links for an answer when I was hit. This happened a few months back too. Basically, your browser is hijacked any a voice and pop-up tells you to call a phone number to remove the virus. This is bogus if you have a good anti-virus.

Comment: At the point you see the pop-up (and hear the voice) I don't think anything permanent has actually happened - it's a "smoke screen". Unfortunately it's very difficult to get out of without deliberately crashing the browser, since the mouse pointer is often hijacked as well. If you were to respond to the pop-ups then I don't know what would happen. (?)

Comment: @w3dk I agree that nothing actually happens. Or at least not so far. Still, I still prefer an ounce of caution. I just thought I would warning folks since this is a site we would all likely visit and it has happened twice in a long span of time. Cheers!!

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I just checked our webmaster chat room and nothing is happen. May be the malware is in your computer and not in website. If they can inject javascript on webmaster chat room then, they can inject on popular chat room as well like android dev. Never seen such a report on other chat room.

Comment: @Goyllo I want to start by saying I value you so incredibly much and I am sorry. ;-) I was referring to SEOChat.com. Thanks ANYWAY! Cheers!!

Comment: I am sorry too. By the way what's you're username there?

Comment: @Goyllo This is the only site I participate in. Short of other SE sites,  I do not  get involved anywhere else. Cheers!!